# Centos 6.6 ignores inittab – always boots to runlevel 3

Tags: centos6, runlevel

Well, like the title says, I have inittab set to id:5:initdefault but it always boots to runlevel 3 (as confirmed by "runlevel" and "who -r")

Typing 'init 5' brings the GUI up.  Also, appending '5' to the kernel grub line also brings up the GUI.

By why is inittab ignored?

Comment: Is the `initdefault` line in `inittab` exactly as you've shown? There should be  colon on the end  - so `id:5:initdefault:`. Although if init didn't recognise the line I'd expect (from the docs) it to prompt for run level.

Comment: sorry, yes, the inittab has the colon on the end so "id:5:initdefault:"  The freshly installed file had that as the absolute last line.  I added an extra blank line below but same result.

Comment: What is in your grub config?  i.e. cat /proc/cmdline   What commands did the OS boot with?  Is there a 3 in the grub config?